# Error message when trying to debug C code on VSCODE

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When trying to debug code, I get the error message "Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-environment-cd c:\uses\...(path)". No such file or directory.

I'm using the last version of both GCC and GDB. Genuinely have no idea how to fix this and could not find answers anywhere. Debugging C code with VSCODE just feels to confusing.

Comment: Debugging is setup in your `launch.json`. You may want to review the official VSCode documentation about this and the other 2 json files: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: You may have to figure out yourself why `c:\uses\...(path)` is no such file or directory. Perhaps you have spaces in the path and that caused the problem. It's best to never use a space in a path or filename in `c` or `c++`

Comment: Check if there are spaces in your path. Spaces in the path may give an error.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?